# Should I refer to true datatype extent when allocating buffer space for receiving custom datatype?

Tags: mpi

I want to send a square grid with side length N from a process to another process which will fill with it a rectangular grid with the same number of rows but extended with one more column at the left (which I want to keep uninitialized for the moment), so having N rows and N+1 columns.
Like shown in the code below, I leverage three different custom datatypes for spacing rows at receiving side (also used in other parts of the code not shown here), one modeling a row made of N MPI_CHAR in the sender matrix (row_t), one got by resizing it to an extent of N+1 bytes by MPI_Type_create_resized (row_t_res), and one consisting in the replication of the latter N times into contiguous locations by MPI_Type_contiguous call (ext_part_t).

My questioni is: assuming I start to fill the receiver matrix (with MPI_Recv) from the second (with index 1) element of the first row (as to keep the first element of the left column uninitialized like the others belonging to it), how many elements I have to allocate at receiver side for avoiding overflow? N*(N+1) (so referring to the true extent of ext_part_t obtained with MPI_get_true_extent, that is N*(N+1)-1) or N*(N+1) +1 (referring to extent got by MPI_get_extent, that is N*(N+1))?
Even if not filled with data, the last (cell of the last) block of row_t_res would cross receiver’s allocated array right boundary and I don’t know if MPI internally accesses it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

typedef signed char cell_type;

void init_domain(cell_type *grid, int N)
{
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < N * N; i++)
   {
       grid[i] = i;
   }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int N = 4;

   cell_type *matrix = NULL;

   int my_rank, comm_sz;

   MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_sz);

   MPI_Datatype row_t, row_t_res, ext_part_t;

   if (0 == my_rank && 2 != comm_sz)
   {
       fprintf(stderr, "Program must be run with exactly 2 processes.\n");
       MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   if (0 == my_rank)
   {
       const size_t sender_matrix_size = (N * N) * sizeof(cell_type);
       matrix = (cell_type *)malloc(sender_matrix_size);

       init_domain(matrix, N);
   }

   MPI_Type_contiguous(N, MPI_CHAR, &row_t);
   MPI_Type_commit(&row_t);

   MPI_Type_create_resized(row_t,       //oldtype
                           0,           //lower bound
                           N + 1,       //extent
                           &row_t_res); //newtype
   MPI_Type_commit(&row_t_res);

   MPI_Type_contiguous(N,            //count
                       row_t_res,    //oldtype
                       &ext_part_t); //newtype
   MPI_Type_commit(&ext_part_t);

   if (0 == my_rank)
   {
       MPI_Send(matrix,          //const void *buf,
                N,               //int count,
                row_t,           //datatype
                1,               //dest
                0,               //tag
                MPI_COMM_WORLD); //comm
   }
   else
   {
       /*
                       +---+---+---+---+
       row_t           | X | X | X | X |
                       +---+---+---+---+
                       ^------ N ------^

                       +---+---+---+---+---+
       row_t_res       | X | X | X | X |   |
                       +---+---+---+---+---+
                       ^------ N ------^   
                       ^------  N+1  ------^

       ext_part_t:
                           +---+---+---+---+
                           | X | X | X | X |
                       +---+---+---+---+---+
                       |   | X | X | X | X |
                       +---+---+---+---+---+
                       |   | X | X | X | X |
                       +---+---+---+---+---+
                       |   | X | X | X | X |
                       +---+---+---+---+---+
                       |   | 
                       +---+

what I have to allocate at receiving side:
                       FIRST_RECV_CELL_IDX
                             |
                       +---+-v-+---+---+---+
                       |   | X | X | X | X |
                       +---+---+---+---+---+
                       |   | X | X | X | X |
                       +---+---+---+---+---+
                       |   | X | X | X | X |
                       +---+---+---+---+---+
                       |   | X | X | X | X |
                       +---+---+---+---+---+

                       |   | ?
                       +---+
*/

       MPI_Aint l, extent, true_extent;
       MPI_Type_get_extent(ext_part_t, &l, &extent);
       MPI_Type_get_true_extent(ext_part_t, &l, &true_extent);

       int receiver_matrix_rows = N;
       int receiver_matrix_cols = N + 1;

       const int FIRST_RECV_CELL_IDX = 1;

       const size_t receiver_matrix_size =
           //(FIRST_RECV_CELL_IDX + true_extent)
           receiver_matrix_rows * receiver_matrix_cols;

       //OR:
       //(FIRST_RECV_CELL_IDX + extent)
       //= receiver_matrix_rows * receiver_matrix_cols + FIRST_RECV_CELL_IDX; ?

       matrix = (cell_type *)malloc(receiver_matrix_size);

       MPI_Recv(&matrix[FIRST_RECV_CELL_IDX], //buf
                1,                            //count
                ext_part_t,                   //datatype
                0,                            //source
                0,                            //tag
                MPI_COMM_WORLD,               //comm
                MPI_STATUS_IGNORE             //status
       );

       /* Using the matrix extended with a left (uninitialized for now) 
       column... */
   }

   free(matrix);
   MPI_Type_free(&row_t);
   MPI_Type_free(&row_t_res);
   MPI_Type_free(&ext_part_t);

   MPI_Finalize();

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Running that code with different N values never showed me such an error, but maybe it is just because of the case (I’m using an OpenMPI 4.0.3 installation; the code can be compiled with mpicc -std=c99 -Wall -Wpedantic -O2 program.c -o program). Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you receive `N+1` elements of a given datatype, you should allocate `N * extent + true_extent` bytes. you can use `valgrind` to spot a memory overflow on the receiver (since this is an undefined behavior, a crash is not guaranteed)

Comment: that is (`N * extent + true_extent`), the true_extent of the contiguous type (made of `N+1` types), isn’t it? (Thanks for valgrind advice too.)

Comment: that's correct.

Comment: It’s also for your answers given here, @gilles, that I keep using also OpenMPI. Best regards.